# How to find coordinate of point on unknown plane?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

There are plane that normal vector is unknown. When know some information, how can I get coordinate of point on plane?

These are information, 
Coordinates of point $A, B, C$ are known, 
Point $A$ is on the plane, 
Distance from plane of point $B$ and $C$ are known, (it makes right triangle) 

And now, I want to know coordinates of $P1$ or $P2$ with above given informations. Finally get normal vector of unknown plane is my plan. I think it looks like possible roughly, but I couldn't get solution. Is it possible?

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXjPr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the plane is $a x+b y+c z+d=0$. We can choose $$a^2+b^2+c^2=1 \ \ (1) $$
Point A is in the plane, so $$a x_A + b y_A + c z_A+d=0\ \ (2)$$
Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html we can write $$D_B=a x_B + b y_B + c z_B+d\ \ (3)\\D_C=a x_C + b y_C + c z_C+d\ \ (4)$$
Here $D_B, D_C$ are the distances from the $B, C$ points to the plane. Notice that I have used equation (1). Now you have 4 equations with 4 unknowns. The normal vector is $(a,b,c)$

Comment: I solved some equations with Matlab, How can I handle when normal vector is imaginary? For example,
$A (0, 1.15, 0), B (1, -0.577, 0), C (-1, 0.577, 0), D_B = 2.71, D_C = 4.22$, normal vector $c$ is $+/-1.8962i$.

Comment: That does not seem right.

Comment: My guess is that one of the distances is positive, one negative. That means that $B$ and $C$ are on different parts of the plane.

Comment: Thanks for additional instruction!